# Overflowing SPWebProvisioningProvider.Provisioning call

Tags: 2010, provisioning-providers

I have implemented a SPWebProvisioningProvider class which overrides the Provision method for a custom site definition. If I don't run any code, I get the 'select a template' page when I open up my new site collection. So I noticed some examples stating that you should call props.Web.ApplyWebTemplate. But when I do; the code seems to run into an andless loop calling the provisioning provider again, resulting in a stack overflow exception.

No one else seems to be having this problem, so I guess I'm making a mistake somewhere; but where?

Comment: Could you please paste code in `Provision` method, and also `webtemp_<your site>.xml` schema file?

Comment: I Would strongly advise not to use custom site definitions, but to use webtemplates, as introduced in SharePoint 2010. Site definitions do give a headache when you want to upgrade them, and they may disappear in vNext. See http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx for more information. Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx for information on how to use them

Comment: Hi Bas, I'm not really using the template, it's empty. The only thing I use it for is feature stapling and firing provisioning code. So I guess I could just as easily use a Web Template instead, won't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found the answer myself. You need to create 2 configurations, one with the provisioning handler linked and one without. The configuration without provisioning code is hidden and that's the one you want to apply using web.ApplyWebTemplate. That way, the provisioning code won't fire again.

Comment: please post the code of  your solution.